# Do we have command to execute multiple arguments in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod running in kubernetes and i need to run two commands in one line.

Say,

```
kubectl exec -it <pod name> -n <namespace > -- bash -c redis-cli
```

above command will open redis-cli

i want to run one more command after exec in one line ie info, i am trying below which is not working:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod name> -n <namespace > -- bash -c redis-cli -- info
```

Comment: Have you checked the answers provided? Did this solved your Issue?

Answer (score 1):

**You have to put your command and all the parameters between apostrophes.**

in your example it would be:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -n <namespace> -- bash -c 'redis-cli info'
```

> **From `Bash manual`: bash -c:** If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument commaqnd_string.

**Other option *(which in my opinion is a better approach)* is to get the output from the command with an instant pod, which creates, runs and deletes the pod right after that, like this:**

```
kubectl run --namespace <YOUR_NAMESPACE> <TEMP_RANDOM_POD_NAME> --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --env REDIS_PASSWORD=$REDIS_PASSWORD --image docker.io/bitnami/redis:5.0.7-debian-10-r0 -- bash -c 'redis-cli -h redis-master -a $REDIS_PASSWORD info'
```

*in my case the password was stored in a envvar called $REDIS_PASSWORD and I'm connecting to a server in a pod called redis-master.
I let it as I runned it to show that you can use as much parameters as needed.*

POC:

```
user@minikube:~$ kubectl run --namespace default redis-1580466120-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --env REDIS_PASSWORD=$REDIS_PASSWORD --image docker.io/bitnami/redis:5.0.7-debian-10-r0 -- bash -c 'redis-cli -h redis-master -a $REDIS_PASSWORD info'
 10:41:10.65 
 10:41:10.66 Welcome to the Bitnami redis container
 10:41:10.66 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis
 10:41:10.66 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis/issues
 10:41:10.67 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
 10:41:10.67 

Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
# Server
redis_version:5.0.7
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
...
{{{suppressed output}}}
...
# CPU
used_cpu_sys:1.622434
used_cpu_user:1.313600
used_cpu_sys_children:0.013942
used_cpu_user_children:0.008014

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
pod "redis-1580466120-client" deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

Not get your question, do you want to get the information from redis-cli?

```
kubernetes exec -it <pod name> -n <namespace > -- bash -c 'redis-cli info'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to link your commands using && ?

`kubernetes exec -it <pod name> -n <namespace > -- bash -c redis-cli && info`